# crystal report format string with dashes

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, string-formatting

I have crystal report in which I want to format the case no into sumthing like this 000-00000-00. I used totext method but it won't work. it says bad number format string. I tried these codes but nothing is working. If you're wondering why i Converted the case no into number first, it is because the Caseno is already in string format and it is giving me "too many argument" error if I do not do that.

```
NumberVar x:=CDBl({vwPriorityAssignmentList.CaseNo});
totext(x, '00000-000-00');
```

or this:

```
If NumericText({vwPriorityAssignmentList.CaseNo}) Then
   ToText(tonumber({vwPriorityAssignmentList.CaseNo}),"000-00000-00")
Else
   {vwPriorityAssignmentList.CaseNo};
```

can anyone help me pls. appreciate it, thanks

Comment: nevermind. found it. LEFT({vwDepositDueList.CaseNo},3) + '-' + Mid ({vwDepositDueList.CaseNo},4,5) + '-' + Right ({vwDepositDueList.CaseNo},2)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the Picture command: `Picture({vwDepositDueList.CaseNo}, "xxxxx-xxx-xx")`

Answer (score -1):

```
picture(totext(tonumber({vwPriorityAssignmentList.CaseNo}),'0000000000'),"xxx-xxxxx-xx")
```

Comment: Code only answers are not helpful for future readers. Add explanation of the code too.